# SQL Server replication question: does all type of articles have row in publication_database.dbo.sysarticles?

Tags: sql-server, replication

From SQL Server Book Online:

```
sysarticles (Transact-SQL)
--------------------------
Contains a row for each article defined in the local database. 
This table is stored in the published database.
```

In my example, it's a transaction replication. I have one table and two procedures published. But when i query the dbo.sysarticles table, there is just one line correspond to the table. I'm curious whether objects of a type other than table have correspond rows in the dbo.sysarticles table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[dbo.sysarticles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187723.aspx) is only used for tables. Your stored procedures should be found in [dbo.sysschemaarticles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182785.aspx) in the published database.